# Center Anchor element with flex attribute inside li element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

using bootstrap (without css if possible) , How can I center text `anchor` inside an `li` element?

```css
.nav-lt-tab .nav-item .nav-link {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-lt-tab justify-content-center" id="tab" role="tablist">
                            <!-- Nav item -->
                            <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill ">
                                <a class="nav-link active text-dark ml-2 mr-2 " id="description-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#description" role="tab" aria-controls="description" aria-selected="false">Description</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
                            </li>
                               <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
                            </li>
                               <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                            </body
                            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `ul` elemnt the `text-center` class and it will be done .
Update your HTML code with the following code

```
<ul class="nav nav-lt-tab justify-content-center text-center" id="tab" role="tablist">
     <!-- Nav item -->
     <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill ">
       <a class="nav-link active text-dark ml-2 mr-2 " id="description-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#description" role="tab" aria-controls="description" aria-selected="false">Description</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item my-2 flex-fill">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark ml-2 mr-2" id="review-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#review" role="tab" aria-controls="review" aria-selected="false"><span class="ml-3">Feedback</span></a>
      </li>
</ul>
```